# Animating ImageView Height

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an image:

[image]

I am adding this image as a source to a custom ImageView:

```
public class TopCropImageView extends ImageView {


public TopCropImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public TopCropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public TopCropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
        float scaleFactor = getWidth()
                / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

And then I am giving only 100dp height to this TopCropImageView in xml and the imageview looks like:

[image]

This is what I wanted.

The problem is that when I click the image, i want it to expand and thus become the first image. Like the banner expands.

I have done this with LayoutParams, but i want to animate it.

I have tried scaled animation but doing that, the smaller part of the image only expands.

I want the imageview to behave like a curtain and thus make the background image visible.
Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a ValueAnimator inside your custom image view.
Have a look here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator

Comment: You tried animating what? You should do a custom ValueAnimator that animates the value you want (in this case the height of the view). I suggest you to have a look at the documentation in the link